# android mysql database returning null only in one field

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, database

I'm pulling data from a database using JSON and MySQL in my android app. It successfully pulls the "Title" and "Image_URL" fields from my database. But my "Content" field, which contains large paragraphs of text, returns null. When I type in some short text, it shows up. But when copy/pasting my long paragraphs it returns null.

the "Content" field I'm using in my database is set to "text". I also tried "longtext", and "varchar (2000)". I tried deleting all inverted commas from my paragraphs too, as I read they can cause issues.

Below is my php code. I don't know anything about php as I'm a beginner to all this but use this simple code and it usually works.

Thank you

```
<?php

$host = "************";

$db = "***********";

$user = "**********";

$pass = "*********";


$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());


$Title=$_REQUEST['Title'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Title= '$Title'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)  {
$output[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: How are you downloading JSON from the server? How do you display it in the app. Post your code.

Comment: try base64 encoding your content an then send it